# how can i use "with-select" in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl

Hello :) im still noobie to vhdl and trying to implement the following with with-select but im getting false logic when implementing to my FBGA i dont know what am missing but somehow its tricky and it would be really nice if someone can tell me where im missing the point ...

what im tring to implement is

o0 = ((not i3) and i1 and i0) or ((not i3) and (not i2) and i1) or (i0 and (not i2)) or (i3  and (not i0))

o1 = ((not i0) and i3) or ((not i3) and (not i2) and i1) or (i0 and i2 and i3 and i1)

o2 = (i0 and i2 and i3 and i1) or ((not i3) and (not i1)) or (i3 and (not i1))

o3 = ((i3) and (not i0)) or ((not i3) and (not i2) and i1) or ((not i3) and i0 and i1)

im trying to rebuild a PROM ... my vhdl code is :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
 
entity with_select is
port(i3,i2,i1,i0 : in std_logic;
      o0,o1,o2,o3:out std_logic
            );
end with_select;
 
architecture behave of with_select is
 signal s_out : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);   
begin
  with i0 select
  o0<=((not i3) and i1 and i0) or ((not i3) and (not i2) and i1) or (i0 and (not i2)) or (i3  and (not i0)) when '1',
    '0' when others;
       with i1 select
  o1<=((not i0) and i3) or ((not i3) and (not i2) and i1) or (i0 and i2 and i3 and i1)  when '1',
    '0' when others;
       with i2 select
  o2<=(i0 and i2 and i3 and i1) or ((not i3) and (not i1)) or (i3 and (not i1)) when '1',
    '0' when others;
       with i3 select
  o3<=((i3) and (not i0)) or ((not i3) and (not i2) and i1) or ((not i3) and i0 and i1) when '1', 
  '0' when others;
 end behave;
```

Comment: Why not simply implement those boolean expressions as written?

Comment: In the `O0` assignment for instance two of the terms don't require `i0` to be '1', yet you require `i0` to be '1' in all four using a '1' choice in the selected assignment statement. You are not implementing the Boolean expressions  you show before the VHDL code faithfully using a selected signal assignment and should implement them directly without the selected signal assignment as Brian suggests. The unary operator **not** is higher priority than operators **and** or **or** in VHDL, you don't need parentheses to express logically inverted values unambiguously here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms are not correct for the Boolean expressions when using a selected signal assignment statement.  The choice '1' requires in the assignment to `o0` for example requires `i0` to be '1' which contradicts the terms:

```vhdl
    with i0 select
    o0 <= ((not i3) and i1 and i0) or 
          ((not i3) and (not i2) and i1) or 
           (i0 and (not i2)) or 
           (i3  and (not i0))   when '1',
          '0' when others;
```

Correcting this requirement can be performed in a selected signal assignment by modifying terms:

```vhdl
-- selected signal assignment statement with corrected terms
    with to_x01(i0) select
       o0s <=
          -- ((not i3) and i1 and i0) or
           (not i3 and i1) or
          -- ((not i3) and (not i2) and i1) or -- met in new term above
          -- (i0 and (not i2)) or              -- as well as new term below
          not i2
          -- (i3  and (not i0))
          when '1',
           (not i3 and not i2 and i1) or
           i3
          when '0',
          'X' when others;  -- because std_logic;
```

but it takes effort to translate.

There are two other types of assignment that will do as well:

```vhdl
-- conditional signal assignment statement equivalent
        o0c <= '1' when (
                       (not i3 and i1 and i0) or 
                       (not i3 and not i2 and i1) or 
                       (i0 and not i2) or 
                       (i3  and not i0)
                       ) = '1' else
              '0';

-- simple signal assignment statement
         o0d <= (not i3 and i1 and i0) or 
               (not i3 and not i2 and i1) or 
               (i0 and not i2) or 
               (i3  and not i0);
```

You can demonstrate the original selected signal assignment statement doesn't match the Boolean expressions:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity with_select_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of with_select_tb is
    signal i0, i1, i2, i3:  std_logic;
    signal o0:              std_logic;  -- original result
    signal o0s:             std_logic;  -- corrected selected signal assignment
    signal o0c:             std_logic;  -- conditional signal assignment
    signal o0d:             std_logic;  -- dataflow simple waveform assignment
    -- for revision less than -2008:
    function to_string (inp: std_logic_vector) return string is
        variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
        alias input_str:  std_logic_vector (1 to inp'length) is inp;
    begin
        for i in input_str'range loop
            image_str(i) := character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(input_str(i)));
        end loop;
        return image_str;
    end function;
begin
-- original selected signal assignment    
    with i0 select
    o0 <= ((not i3) and i1 and i0) or 
          ((not i3) and (not i2) and i1) or 
           (i0 and (not i2)) or 
           (i3  and (not i0))   when '1',
          '0' when others;

-- selected signal assignment statement with corrected terms
    with to_x01(i0) select
       o0s <=
          -- ((not i3) and i1 and i0) or
           (not i3 and i1) or
          -- ((not i3) and (not i2) and i1) or -- met in new term above
          -- (i0 and (not i2)) or              -- as well as new term below
          not i2
          -- (i3  and (not i0))
          when '1',
           (not i3 and not i2 and i1) or
           i3
          when '0',
          'X' when others;  -- because std_logic;
               
-- conditional signal assignment statement equivalent
        o0c <= '1' when (
                       (not i3 and i1 and i0) or 
                       (not i3 and not i2 and i1) or 
                       (i0 and not i2) or 
                       (i3  and not i0)
                       ) = '1' else
              '0';

-- simple signal assignment statement
         o0d <= (not i3 and i1 and i0) or 
                (not i3 and not i2 and i1) or 
                (i0 and not i2) or 
                (i3 and not i0);

STIMULI:
    process
    begin
        report LF & HT & "(i3, i2, i1, i0)" & HT &
                 "o0  " & "o0s " & "o0c " & "o0d ";
        for i in 0 to 15 loop
            (i3, i2, i1, i0) <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i,4));
            wait for 10 ns;
            report LF & HT & to_string(std_logic_vector'(i3, i2, i1, i0)) &
                   HT & HT & HT &
                   std_ulogic'image(o0)  & " " &
                   std_ulogic'image(o0s) & " " &
                   std_ulogic'image(o0c) & " " &
                   std_ulogic'image(o0d);
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
    
end architecture foo;
```

which produces:

```
ghdl -r with_select_tb
with_select.vhdl:92:9:@0ms:(report note):
        (i3, i2, i1, i0)        o0  o0s o0c o0d
with_select.vhdl:97:13:@10ns:(report note):
        0000                    '0' '0' '0' '0'
with_select.vhdl:97:13:@20ns:(report note):
        0001                    '1' '1' '1' '1'
with_select.vhdl:97:13:@30ns:(report note):
        0010                    '0' '1' '1' '1'
with_select.vhdl:97:13:@40ns:(report note):
        0011                    '1' '1' '1' '1'
with_select.vhdl:97:13:@50ns:(report note):
        0100                    '0' '0' '0' '0'
with_select.vhdl:97:13:@60ns:(report note):
        0101                    '0' '0' '0' '0'
with_select.vhdl:97:13:@70ns:(report note):
        0110                    '0' '0' '0' '0'
with_select.vhdl:97:13:@80ns:(report note):
        0111                    '1' '1' '1' '1'
with_select.vhdl:97:13:@90ns:(report note):
        1000                    '0' '1' '1' '1'
with_select.vhdl:97:13:@100ns:(report note):
        1001                    '1' '1' '1' '1'
with_select.vhdl:97:13:@110ns:(report note):
        1010                    '0' '1' '1' '1'
with_select.vhdl:97:13:@120ns:(report note):
        1011                    '1' '1' '1' '1'
with_select.vhdl:97:13:@130ns:(report note):
        1100                    '0' '1' '1' '1'
with_select.vhdl:97:13:@140ns:(report note):
        1101                    '0' '0' '0' '0'
with_select.vhdl:97:13:@150ns:(report note):
        1110                    '0' '1' '1' '1'
with_select.vhdl:97:13:@160ns:(report note):
        1111                    '0' '0' '0' '0'
```

The simple signal assignment resembles the original Boolean expressions. You could provide parentheses around occurrences of the unary not operator and it's operand to match style. VHDL prioritizes **not** over other logical operators and the parentheses are not required.

---

Note report statement format is VHDL tool implementation dependent.